# Pass object from dispatch listener to the controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

So I have a dispatch event listener in Module.php, that retrives user object from database, and sets layout variable with it.
I want to access the very same object in controller. How can I pass it?

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
    {

        $eventManager       = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
        $app = $e->getParam('application');
        $app->getEventManager()->attach('dispatch', array($this, 'setPortfolioLayout'));

    }

    /**
     * This event will set $user variable in layout when it's active
     *
     * @param MvcEvent $e
     */
    public function setPortfolioLayout(MvcEvent $e)
    {

        $matchedRoute = $e->getRouteMatch();

        if($matchedRoute->getParam('isPortfolio')) {

            $em = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'); /** @var ObjectManager $em */
            $user = $em->getRepository('Application\Entity\User')->findOneBy(['login' => $matchedRoute->getParam('login')]);

            if(! $user) {
                $e->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404); return;
            }

            $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
            $viewModel->setVariable('user', $user);
            $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/portfolio');

            $matchedRoute->setParam('user', $user);

        }
    }
```

I've tried setting the RouteMatch parameter - not the best place to do it, and it is not visible in Controller.
There's a `$e->getController()` method in listener. Should I add a special method for setting the user object for every controller that expects it (adding interfaces traits etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the layout parameters you set in the controller pretty easily:

```
$user = $this->layout()->user;
```

Also, you mentioned you cannot access RouteMatch parameters in the controller, but you actually can:

```
$user = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('user');
```

Additionally, if the "user" is a hard-dependency of this particular controller, I see nothing wrong with setting it into the ServiceManager (before dispatch, so you'd need to increase the priority of your dispatch listener in your example) and making it a hard dependency (constructor injection) of the controller. You'd then create a factory for your controller which constructs the controller like:

```
return new MyController($sm->get('active-user'));
```

In this case, you'd want to be careful to make sure that you have adequate controls in place to make sure this controller can't be dispatched in situations where there might *not* be an 'active-user' service (or whatever you call it).